# My first phonegap app flashlight is failing on cordova build

Tags: android, cordova

I tried my best to follow all the instructions. I'm using this plugin - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin

And here is the full app I wrote - https://github.com/c0debreaker/flashlight-phonegap

Here is the error when I execute cordova build:

```
$ cordova build
Running command: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
/Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug/xml/config.xml:20: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /usr/local/bin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /usr/local/bin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-22/android.jar -M /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package io.cordova.hellocordova -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug/xml/config.xml:20: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.917 secs

/Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `config.xml`, where you have no namespace import for `gap`:
[image]

You can do two things:

1. Add this namespace to the `widget` tag: [image]
2. Or remove the `gap` prefix in `gap:plugin` as these days you can use `plugin` directly on phonegap build.

Comment: Got it Eddy. I'll try it soon. Thanks.